# create multi level menu with routerlink that doesn't close after click on any routed item in angular 2

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular2-routing

I want to create a multi level dropdown menu with routerLink that after clicking on any item, it doesn't close, so on a routed component, active routed menu opened.
How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not giving you the code, only the solution :

First, you should have a component that contains both the menu and the router-outlet.

In its TS, you should have a `showMenu` boolean, that is true when your user clicks on / hovers over your menu, and flase when your user clicks again / mouseleaves.

When it's true, your menu should be shown (with a `*ngIf` condition in your code).

If you do that, your menu should be visible even when you change route (because the menu isn't included in the router outlet, its logic is handled by the "parent" component, which won't change its state on route change).